# c# Multi Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I got a printing service that will now also do file integrations, in order to do both tasks side by side I though about using Threads.

After seeing this [Thread Tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/thread) I then searched for what [Join do.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx)

If I'm not wrong, Join terminates the thread, right? So my question here, since the service should be running 24/7 until someone need to stop the Thread, can I just do a Thread.Sleep to make them wait for the next interaction instead of Join and Start them again?

Even if they are working in different methods with different objects can they still giving deadlocks? Since it's for a service I can't have it giving deadlocks times to times.

**EDIT:** I did the following test and it seems to be working well, anyome with more experience using threads can check if would cause me problems later? (This code is a test sample, it is not my service).

[My sample](http://rextester.com/NZB22142)

Comment: "Join terminates thread, right?". Reading your link: "Join waits for a thread to finish"

Comment: Yes, but if I want the Thread to stay alive I have to avoid the Join, right?

Comment: I would recommend using Tasks, give this a read http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism

Comment: @Evk I added a sample, can you check it and tell me if it could give me problems later? I edited my question, this is not my actual service, just a sample that I'm using to test the Threads before implement.

Answer (score 1):

> Join terminates the thread, right?

No, it waits until the thread is done.

> can I just do a Thread.Sleep to make them wait for the next interaction instead of Join and Start them again?

Yes, you can do that. Depending on your architecture, you could also use a `BlockingCollection` to queue items to process in a separate thread, and executing them in another.

> Even if they are working in different methods with different objects can they still giving deadlocks?

Well, they can if you write your code the wrong way. There is no quick and easy fix for this, besides keeping in mind all the time that two methods could call some shared code at the exact same time, causing race conditions and deadlocks.

Comment: But I just should use the Join if I want to kill the thread, right? If I want it to keep running for a long time I should avoid the Join.

Comment: No, as said, `Join` waits until the thread is done. It doesn't kill a thread. `Abort` does that.

Comment: Ok. I notice in a test that I did, that .Start make it run only once, to make a loop I should use .Start everytime I wanted it to run? For example in my Run() that is called by my HandleRun() with a Thread.Sleep(), Should I put a Thread.Start()?

Comment: I updated my question with a sample, can you give a quick check and see if that would work fine or if would give me any problems later?

Comment: It is better for you to read some documentation than to let us comment on an open ended dump of code.